# Expressing "As..."

Tags: grammar

So the grammatical ending 듯(이) is added after a verb or adjective, and is used to mean "as...". So I have two questions:

1. What is the difference between adding 이 and not adding?

My experience in Korean tell me that it is the problem of consonants followed. I think 이 is added if the next consonant is ㅎ or ㅇ, and otherwise just 듯.

However mostly I will just treat adding 이 as the formal version only.

2. What is the difference between 듯(이) and 는 것처럼?

Answer (score 6):

듯 is simply a contraction of 듯이, and are completely interchangable, as stated by the standard dictionary.

듯, 듯이 both can be used as depedent nouns, or connective verb endings.

### dependent noun usage

Dependent nouns are nouns, so they are considered as full words and must have spaces around them. Also they are dependent, which means they must have an attributive modifying them.

1. making similies

> 경기장에서는 관중들의 함성이 하늘을 찌를 듯이 울려 퍼졌다. The cheers of the audience echoed as if it would reach the sky.

2. guesses

> 곧 태풍이 불어닥칠 듯이 파도가 높고 거세게 일기 시작했다. The tides got high and strong, as if a storm would start sooner of later.

3. pretending

> 그는 마치 인도에 가 본 듯이 이야기했다. He talked as if he had actually been to India.

## verb ending usage

Verb endings aren't actual words, they just stick to end of verbs and make what we call a "conjugation". So it's never spaced.

> 구름에 달 가듯이 둘은 꼭 붙어다녔다. The two always went together, like how the moon follows the cloud[proverb].
>   아이들은 경쟁이라도 하듯이 식당으로 뛰어들어왔다. The children ran into the cafeteria as if they were on some kind of a race.

-는 것처럼 is interchangable with the verb ending usage of 듯(or 듯이), since -는 is an attributive veb ending.